# How can I retrieve a model from AutoDesk CLOUD and display it in AutoDesk Viewer3D, I already have the modelGuid and projectGuid

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

My path until now:

Got my projects (Revit projects);

Folder Content;

Project Files, which already has the versions with `projectGuid` and `modelGuid`.

How do I retrieve the model and display it in the AutoDek Viewer?

I know how to do it locally with buckets etc., but I'm trying to do it with the projects in cloud.

Someone give a sign of what I'm doing wrong or if I'm very far from the right way to do it

Comment: Please update with code or more details so we can help you better - things like "AutoDek Viewer" tend to indicate not enough attention to those details which we cannot help with unless we can see them.  Are you getting errors? things like that

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Thanks for the answer but, that's the thing, I don't know the way to do it and I don't find it anywhere in the web, so I'm not receiving any errors.
I see in web examples that I need to download the rvt file, upload it in a bucket, transalate it and then generate a urn to display in the viewer, so with the project in cloud URN can I display it simply display it? or do I need anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're interested in loading existing designs (from applications such as Autodesk Construction Cloud or BIM360) into your custom viewer app, we have a tutorial specifically for that: https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/hubs-browser.

Comment: Man, you just saved me, thank you very mutch